# error with first simple game with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

def loadimage(name, colorkey=None):
    try:
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join(name))
    except pygame.error, message:
        print "Failed to load image ",name


class Userplane(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image, self.rect = loadimage("userplane.bmp")

    def update(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.midtop = pos

def main():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((255,255,255))


    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    user = Userplane()
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((user))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while 1:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return

        allsprites.update()

    screen.blit(background(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

hi im very new, ive just finished the codeacademy course and the chimppunch game in the pygame tutorial. Im using almost an exact copy of that game but instead im trying to display a plane at the bottom of the screen instead of a fist. my Userplane class keeps throwing the following error and i dont know why, 'typeerror: 'nonetype' object is not iterable

Comment: where is your traceback?

Comment: On which line is the error occurring? I'm guessing on `for event in pygame.event.get():` but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in your loadimage function.

It does not return the loaded image, so python is complaining that you are trying to assign `self.image, self.rect` from a NoneType.

In Python if a function does not return anything, it is assumed to return None.

Comment: `loadimage ()` probably failed because the image file wasn't found.

Comment: Or the image was found, and it was never returned.

Comment: Whether the "print "Failed to load image " message was printed or not would differentiate the two potential problems.

Comment: True, but I don't think OP would have posted this, if he saw that error message.

Comment: It' hard to tell because both result in the same `TypeError` because of the more fundamental problem you've pointed out. Guess I shouldn't have said "probably" in my initial comment.